# convert string to number without 'replace' Python

Tags: python, string

I take the current exchange rate from the bank's website as a string and I want to convert this string into a number for further calculations and I want to do it as beautifully as possible.

How to convert the string **77,4651 $** to **77.4651** in float format without using func 'replace'?

Comment: `float("77.4651 $".split(" ")[0])`

Comment: sorry, I didn’t indicate that there is a comma in the line instead of a dot, initially the line looks like 77,4651 $

Comment: And what is wrong with replace?

Comment: `float('.'.join("77,4651 $".split(" ")[0].split(',')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float regular expression to make sure, that you get the float number

```py
txt = "77.4651 $"
x = float(re.search("[-+]?[0-9]*(?:\.?[0-9]*)[1]", txt).string)
```

or less safe split by spaces

```py
float("77.4651 $".split("\s+")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex would be useful here to account for varying formats:

```
import re
float('.'.join(re.findall('[0-9]+', "77,4651 $")))
```